# WPF user control and WinForm do not display icons

Tags: wpf, winforms

I'm trying to put WPF user control on the `WinForm` using `ElementHost` but as a result of my icons are not displayed on the button.

http://gyazo.com/7dc201e30246b2b2676060de0ebf35a9

http://gyazo.com/67f039ce310d17a2d270c816ebc5fb3b

```
<ToolBar>
    <Button>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/document-add2.png"  Stretch="None" Margin="0,0,3,0" />
                <TextBlock>Добавить стратегию</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>

    <Button>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/document-delete2.png"  Stretch="None" Margin="0,0,3,0" />
            <TextBlock>Удалить стратегию</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>

    <Separator></Separator>

    <Button>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/document-control_play.png"  Stretch="None" Margin="0,0,3,0" />
            <TextBlock>Запустить стратегию</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>

    <Separator></Separator>

    <Button>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/document-gear.png"  Stretch="None" Margin="0,0,3,0" />
            <TextBlock>Изменить настройки</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
</ToolBar>
```

Comment: I believe your images path are wrong. Where are located those images in your project? Are they also marked as "resources"?

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify your `siteoforigin`?

If the images can be found in the same project, try:

```
<Button>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/document-gear.png"  Stretch="None" Margin="0,0,3,0" />
        <TextBlock>Изменить настройки</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

So: `pack://application:,,,/[path from root of project]`